# Active-Directory Connectivity test and some configuration details

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

We are developing a web application in java with spring security. I tasked to add support for authenticating our users against Active Directory.
For this, I promoted one of our 2008 server to domain control and added a snippet with ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider spring class to authenticate login user.
It worked fine with ldap and ldaps protcols.

But couple of questions:

1)ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider constructor is only taking AD url and domain name unlike LdapAuthenticationProvider for OpenLDAP, which needs mote input details like managerDN, manager password, user search base and group search base etc. Shouldn't Active Directory need all this data? I thought at least it would need manager user/password to allow connections! Of course, in my test routine, I supplied only url and domain and it successfully authenticated users.

2) I need to write quick connectivity test routine to verify whether user entered AD url and domain are valid or not. How to do it?

Btw, our application will be deployed on Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Able to do connectivity test using following snippet:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://dc.example.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");

try {
   new InitialDirContext(env);
} catch (NamingException e) {
   // not connected
}
```

Still trying to understand that url and domain information is enough to talk to AD or in some cases needed to supply more object information.